# I have a scenebuilder text that doesnt show up on scenebuilder

Tags: javafx, fxml

so here is the text code of my fxml file :

i want this to be opened by scenebuilder , i have everything setup but it doesnt work

every time I run it , its either they ask me to download javafx and i cant do it or it just doesn't show up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" padding="25" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="example.RegistrationFormController">
    <Label text="Create New Account" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
        <font>
            <Font size="18" />
        </font>
    </Label>

    <Label text="Username:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    <TextField fx:id="usernameTextField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />

    <Label text="Email Address:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
    <TextField fx:id="emailTextField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />

    <Label text="Password:" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
    <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />

    <Label text="Confirm Password:" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
    <PasswordField fx:id="confirmPasswordField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="center" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
        <Button text="Create Account" onAction="#registerAccount" />
        <Button text="Cancel" onAction="#cancelRegistration" />
    </HBox>

    <Label fx:id="errorLabel" textFill="#1c2280" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
        <padding>
            <Insets top="10" />
        </padding>
    </Label>
</GridPane>
```

Answer (score 2):

**How to fix your error**

Change:

```
<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" padding="25" . . .
```

To:

```
<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="example.RegistrationFormController">
  <padding>
    <Insets bottom="25.0" left="25.0" right="25.0" top="25.0" />
  </padding>
  . . . 
</GridPane>
```

After this your FXML opens fine in SceneBuilder (tested in JavaFX Scene Builder 18.0.0).

**How to debug your error**

If you try to open your original FXML file in SceneBuilder, it will show a dialog box:

[image: cannot open]

Clicking on "**Show Details...**" provides a stack trace that tells you what went wrong:

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/send2/sample.fxml:41

    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.handleUnknownAndMissingCauses(FXOMLoader.java:119)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.handleKnownCauses(FXOMLoader.java:126)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.handleFxmlLoadingError(FXOMLoader.java:112)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:106)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:115)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2561)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:764)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:398)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:675)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleOpenFilesAction(SceneBuilderApp.java:514)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.welcomedialog.WelcomeDialogWindowController.handleOpen(WelcomeDialogWindowController.java:220)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.welcomedialog.WelcomeDialogWindowController.openDocument(WelcomeDialogWindowController.java:215)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@18/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.controls@18/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.controls@18/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.controls@18/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base@18/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/send2/sample.fxml:41

    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:104)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to coerce 25 to class javafx.geometry.Insets.
    at javafx.fxml@18/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.coerce(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@18/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@18/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.applyProperty(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processValue(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(Unknown Source)
    ... 65 more
```

The key parts being:

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/C:/Users/<username>/sample.fxml:41
. . .
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to coerce 25 to class javafx.geometry.Insets.
```

On line 41 of the FXML, the parser encountered a number rather than an expected `Insets` type.  The `GridPane` is a multi-line element that doesn't close until line 41.  The actual error is in the attribute in the start of the `GridPane` xml tag, where you have `padding="25"`.

Elsewhere in your FXML, with the `fxid="errorLabel"` label, you already specify padding in the correct way.  This is done by adding an additional element to specify the padding rather than trying to set the padding via an attribute.  To pad your `GridPane` you need something similar.

Most good IDEs (e.g. Idea) will highlight the locations of many types of errors in FXML files.  The IDE will provide descriptions of the errors while you are editing the files, so that you can immediately be aware of the errors and fix them.  Or you can just stick to doing the majority of your editing in SceneBuilder, which will always create well formed FXML files.